# Using the search function in Google scripts array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a function to search for regex in a cell and return a given value if the result is found.
The function works per cell, but I can't get it to work by array applying the function to B1:B10 rather than just B10. I want it to work as array to speed up the function.
I am receiving this error message when I apply pagetype function to an array.
TypeError: Cannot find function search in object yfhhh. (line 13).
I understand that I need to edit the function somehow to have it working on a range of cells  but am not sure how...this is my code:

```js
function pageType(string) {
  if (string.map)          // Test whether input is an array.
    return string.map(page); // Recurse over array if so.
   else {
    return page(string);
  }
}

function page(url) {
var productpage = /.*\.html.*/
var homepage = /^http:\/\/www\.domain.com\/$/
var categorypage = /^http:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/.*/
  if (url.search(categorypage) > -1)
    return "Category Page";
  if (url.search(productpage) > -1)
    return "Product Page";
  if (url.search(homepage) > -1)
    return "Homepage";
      else
    return "Brand Page";
        }
```

Comment: If you apply your function to a range of cells `string` is an array of arrays, each array representing one row. So you could try `return string.map(function(row) {return row.map(page)})`

Comment: Thanks @SpiderPig, this change does what I require and makes sense, so I am applying the function to each row within the range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `search()` method for an array.  An array is a sub category of the broader category of object.  Then there is a JSON object, which is an object.

object - includes

- JSON object {'key':'value'}
- Array ['element1','element2']

An array is a sub category of an object.  It's kind of confusing to call an array an object.  But that is what the error message is doing.

Because you are using RegEx, you can't use `indexOf()`, which is a method of both a string and an array.

You could covert the array to a string:

```
var myArray = myArray.toString();
```

and then search the string for the match.  In your case, you are returning a pre-defined value, so that should work.  It doesn't seem that you need to extract something from the array after a match is found.  Which would require more processing.

```
if (typeof url === 'object') {//If data is an array
  url = url.toString();
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea. That way you can search the entire array in one search.  without having to iterate through each element. I'll have to remember that. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I have used this solution and works as I require but there is one thing I don't understand. The url.toString converts my range (lets say its A1:A3) to a string separated by commas: www.domain.com,www.domain.com/nike, www.domain.com/redtrainers.html .

The function page searches through each individual element in the converted string, so I get a result for each of those values in A1:A3. But if I apply page function on one cell that already has the value www.domain.com,www.domain.com/nike, www.domain.com/redtrainers.html, I only get one result?

Comment: The JavaScript method `search()` returns the starting position of the first match.  The method `search()` will not return multiple starting position numbers if there are multiple matches.  [JavaScript Information - Search with Reg Ex](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp)  Does that answer your question?  If my answer solved you problem, you can mark it as correct by clicking the big green check mark.